# Como desabilitar Multitasking support para aplicativo iPad/iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode

O aplicativo esta funcionando nos aparelhos, porem ao enviar para Apple Store, o seguinte erro aparece:

> Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires these orientations: ...

Como posso desabilitar essa **Multitasking support** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/QuickStartForSlideOverAndSplitView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015145-CH13-SW1)

> **NOTE:**
>   If you must **opt out** of Slide Over and Split View, do so explicitly by adding the `UIRequiresFullScreen` key to your Xcode project’s **Info.plist** file and apply the Boolean value **YES**. You can do this in the property list editor or in the **General** > **Deployment Info** area in the target editor.

Ou seja, tem que adicionar `UIRequiresFullScreen` em sua **Info.plist**, para fazer isso basta marcar o checkbox **Requires full screen** dentro de **Selecione o Target** > **General** > **Deployment Info** no seu XCode, como mostrado na imagem abaixo:

[image]